# How to generate a database diagram/ER diagram from Liquibase database changelog.xml files?

Tags: relational-database, liquibase, entity-relationship

Is there a tool or a way to generate an ER-diagram or database schema from the changelog.xmls of Liquibase Database?

Using database diagram option with IntelliJ did not generate a diagram (it is a package kind of diagram).

Answer (score 1):

The closest that I have gotten to something like this was to first use the Liquibase update command to populate a MS SQL Server database, and then use the diagramming tools built into SQL Server Management Studio to create a diagram. That won't work for people not on MS SQL, but if you are using that platform that is an option. Other platforms might have similar tooling.

Sounds like a great addition though!